# a = int(input()) b = int(input()) if a > b: for number in range(a,b+1): print(number) else: for c in range(b,a+1): print(c)

Tags: python, range

Hi I want it to print all number in the range but I only get back the input numbers.  Not sure why.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

if a > b:
  for number in range(a,b+1):
    print(number)
else:
  for c in range(b,a+1):
      print(c)
```

Comment: Your conditions are completely backwards.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when `a > b` you print numbers from `a` to `b+1` instead of what I think you actually want (`b` to `a+1`). Inverting your condition should make it work.

```
>>> a = int(input())
0
>>> b = int(input())
5
>>> if a > b:
...     for number in range(b, a+1):
...         print(number)
... else:
...     for number in range(a, b+1):
...         print(number)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Also you may get rid of that condition using built-in [max](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#max) and [min](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#min) functions.

```
>>> a = int(input())
10
>>> b = int(input())
20
>>> for number in range(min(a, b), max(a, b) + 1):
...     print(number)
... 
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

The documentation for [range](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-range) may also interest you.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Silly mistake.